# MDX - icCube - How can i Change the status of a cell in a Pie Chart to be non selectable

Tags: mdx, iccube

My report Contains a Pie Chart( Top 5 Clients and "Other") , i want just to click on the 5 clients but not the cell "Other".
Is there a way to resolve this ? Txs, Marwen.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the time being